# /sbin/upstart cpu usage

Tags: 16.04, cpu, upstart

I have randomly getting >80% CPU usage from:

`/sbin/upstart --user`

[image]

Any idea how to stop that and the reason why is this happening?

version:

```
>>>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some fault (or an entirely missing) systemd service, could you check if you even have systemd by `systemctl -v`?

Maybe you already have systemd but are not booting with it? In that case, could you go to your GRUB options at startup and boot by selecting your kernel + (systemd)?